# Django custom user edit form: get_fieldsets() error

Tags: python, django

In Django's `admin.py`, why, even though this works:

```
class StudentAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form     = UserCreationForm
    form         = CustomChangeForm
    fieldsets    = UserAdmin.fieldsets
```

these do not?

```
class StudentAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form     = UserCreationForm
    form         = CustomChangeForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj = None):
        return UserAdmin.fieldsets
```

or

```
class StudentAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form     = UserCreationForm
    form         = CustomChangeForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj = None):
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
```

Shouldn't they be equivalent?

The second set gives me an exception `u"Key 'password' not found in Form"`, while the first one works fine.

The point, in the long term, is obviously to get more specific things working, but first I'd like to figure out what I got wrong so far.

Similarly, adding:

```
    inlines = (MyInline,)
```

to the class works. But adding this:

```
    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        return (MyInline,)
```

throws the exception: `unbound method get_formset() must be called with MyInline instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)`. To the extent of my understanding, these two should also be equivalent.

Thanks.